# SQL Max(Date) in where clause

Tags: sql, max, where-clause

Using SQL Server

I am working with the below 2 tables and am looking to answer the following question: *Find the most current pay rate and change date for all employees.*

Table 1: EmployeePayHistory

1. BusinessEntityID
2. RateChangeDate
3. Rate

Table 2: Employee

1. BusinessEntityID (employee ID)

The SQL statement I produced but not working:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    e.BusinessEntityID as [Employee], eph.rate
FROM 
    humanresources.employee AS e 
JOIN 
    humanresources.employeepayhistory as eph ON e.BusinessEntityID = eph.BusinessEntityID
GROUP BY 
    e.BusinessEntityID, eph.Rate
HAVING 
    MAX(eph.ratechangedate)
```

I have also tried:

```
SELECT 
    e.BusinessEntityID AS [Employee], eph.rate, 
    MAX(eph.RateChangeDate)
FROM 
    humanresources.employee AS e 
JOIN 
    humanresources.employeepayhistory as eph ON e.BusinessEntityID = eph.BusinessEntityID
GROUP BY 
    E.BusinessEntityID, eph.Rate
```

I am having difficulty understanding how to show the most recent `RateChangeDate` per `BusinessEntityID`. I thought the `Group By` function and `MAX` date would solve it. Any suggestions?

Comment: what RDBMS and version are you using?

Comment: How does ur input/output data look like... post some sample data

Answer (score 3):

Depending on your database, there may be an easier option (such as using `row_number`).  However, here's a generic approach with a `join`:

```
select e.BusinessEntityID, e.RateChangeDate, e.Rate
from EmployeePayHistory e
    join (select BusinessEntityID, max(RateChangeDate) RateChangeDate
          from EmployeePayHistory
          group by BusinessEntityID) e2 on e.BusinessEntityID = e2.BusinessEntityID 
                                       and e.RateChangeDate = e2.RateChangeDate
```

If your database supports `window functions`, then this should work:

```
select *
from (
    select *,
       row_number() over (partition by BusinessEntityID order by RateChangeDate desc) as rn
    from EmployeePayHistory 
    ) t
where rn = 1
```

Comment: Thanks, the first option worked well using join. Can you explain why when you include "e.RateChangeDate = e2.RateChangeDate" it eliminates the repetitive BusinessEntityID's? I think that is where I was getting caught up on this query.

Comment: @CafeRacer -- first look at what the subquery returns.  it returns the max change date per entity.  then you can join that back to the original table to return the other fields needed per max date per entity.